# Validate new row in SmartGWT ListGrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I use ListGrid without datasource. And I use validator for some fields.
But then I add new record, it is not validated till I change value in new record.
I don't want to use `grid.startEditingNew()`, because if I don't change them, they do not have Record instance.

```java
    ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
    grid.setCanEdit(true);
    ListGridField field1 = new ListGridField("attr1", "Name1");
    ListGridField field2 = new ListGridField("attr2", "Name2");

    CustomValidator validator = new CustomValidator() {

                @Override
                protected boolean condition(Object value) {
                    Logger.log("Validate: " + value);
                    return true;

                }
            };
    field1.setValidators(validator);
    field2.setValidators(validator);
    grid.setFields(field1, field2);

    Label addButton = new Label();
    //...
    addButton.setTooltip("Add");
    addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(final ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                    ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
                    grid.addData(record);
             // we can use grid.startEditingNew() instead
                }
    });
```

How I can force validation of the new row? Calling `grid.validateRow(grid.getRecords().length - 1)` do not lead to calling the validatior.

Answer (score 0):

Why not validate values being set to the new Record instance (from FormItems?) instead?
You can reuse validators on ListGridField and FormItem.